# fancyapps | Fancybox on click not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox

I am using this library to show fancyboxes:
https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/quick-start

Now I want to execute a function when `next` is triggered in the fancybox but I can't get it to work.

Here is the script I am currently using:

```
Fancybox.bind("[data-fancybox]", {
    next: function() {
        return(console.log('Next called');
    }
});
```

But it is not working, does someone know why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show where exactly in the documentation you found that such a `next` event would exist ...?

Comment: @CBRoe; here is click function with next: https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/options

Comment: That is an option named `click`, that can take `next` as one of the possible values - that is something completely different, than what you have written above. And the purpose of that `click` option is to specify, what should happen, when the backdrop gets clicked - `next` says, show the next item. You could specify your own callback function here instead - but then it would not automatically go to the next item any more, you would have to implement that yourself in your callback function then.

Comment: I think you are looking in the wrong place to begin with here - what you actually want, is to react to one of the _events_ this provides, https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/events

Answer (score 0):

your code is not syntactically correct. Exemaple, should look like this:

```
Fancybox.bind("[data-fancybox]",{
    next: ()=>{
        return(console.log('Next called'));
    }
});
```

But for events, you need use https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/events
like as https://jsfiddle.net/wfkbugpq/2/